# Django & Celery, tasks not activating if using venv

Tags: django, celery, python-venv

I've started using Celery in my Django project, Redis is a broker. Everything is fine when I install Celery globally.

But when I install Celery to a virtual environment, all tasks are sort of stuck. Flower shows that all tasks are "Processed" and none are Active. Worker's output with debug option is like this:

```
[2019-03-18 13:45:13,247: INFO/MainProcess] Received task: (data)
[2019-03-18 13:45:13,247: DEBUG/MainProcess] TaskPool: Apply <(data...)>
..etc
```

There is no "Task accepted: (data)" message

What can be the reason? I use:

```
Django==2.1.7
celery==4.3.0rc2
flower==0.9.2
redis==3.2.0
```

Python v3.7.2, Windows 10